# .NET Fingerprint SDK

Tags: c#, .net, fingerprint, biometrics

I am looking for a comparison of Fingerprint reader SDKs available for .NET (we are using .Net 3.5). My requirements are
  1. Associate more than one fingerprint with a person.
  2. Store the fingerprints it self. (So I do not have to change the Database for my program.)
  3. Work in both event and no-event mode. (Event Mode: Give notification if someone swipes a finger on the reader; No-Event mode: I activate the reader in synchronous mode).
  4. Should provide API for either confirming a user or Identifying a user. (Confirm API: I send the person's ID/unique number and it confirms that it is the same person; Identifying API: The sdk sends the person's ID after it looks up the person using the fingerprint)

I would also like to get a comparison of Fingerprint readers if anybody knows of one available on the internet.

Hope I was clear.

Thanks,
Kishore.

Answer (score 3):

If QFinger is a little too much, try [http://www.grfinger.com/].

GrFinger is a pretty simple SDK that requires no server, etc.  You can store the fingerprint it captures as a byte[] in however form you choose.  We stored them as VARBINARY(MAX) in SQL Server, but you can do whatever your situation calls for.

Comment: This link is leading to a website in chinese! Anyone knows where to find it in English?

Comment: This was a loooong time ago. If I had to guess, GrFinger doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I already worked with the SDK from Queaso. There SDK support the features that you request.
But you better contact them for more details.

*** The product is called [QFinger](http://www.queaso.be/what-we-do/products/queaso-products/qfinger/). You can also find there a list of readers...

---

QFinger No longer exists just for an update.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking for a comparison of fingerprint reader SDKs, here is one you can start with.
You can look up the [BioPlugin SDK](http://www.m2sys.com/bioplugin/) from M2SYS. This SDK allows developers to rapidly integrate multi-modal biometric software with any Windows or web software. It supports any SQL compliant database, including MS SQL Server, Access, MySQL, Oracle 9i, DB2, Informix etc.

Since you also want to get a comparison of fingerprint scanners, Here are two I can recommend:

1. The M2-EasyScan™ USB Fingerprint Reader. The M2-EasyScan™ fingerprint reader is a rugged, ergonomic fingerprint reader that ensures a consistent image quality and accurate results, even in high throughput environments.It captures a high quality image and will not degrade with frequent usage.
2. M2-EasyScan Pro™. This one is most suitable for both large scale or small scale fingerprint identification. It’s thick, anti-scratch coating on the scanning surface endures long term heavy duty usage in any harsh environment without any difficulty. FBI certified to be compliant with PIV- 071006 image quality specifications for single fingerprint readers, the scanner is built to capture single fingerprint images from dry, moist, aged, scarred, and difficult to scan fingers for greater accuracy and reliability.

You can also Google for fingerprint scanners and you will come up with a wide variety of options you can choose from.